# ssh: connect to host username@somehost port 22: connection refused

Tags: server, ssh, firewall

Before you mark it as duplicate, I know it's been asked before, but I tried the solutions that are accepted, nothing worked for me yet.

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, I had the server mounted using `sshfs` and I was editing some python codes (so I wasn't playing around with any ssh config stuff). Anyway, suddenly the server was unmounted (I'm guessing the internet connection was interrupted) and now I have the `port 22: connection refused` problem.

I have tried the following:

1. Turning off and on.
2. Connecting from another device, and it works properly, so the problem must be my computer and not the remote server.
3. Removing ssh and ssh-client `sudo apt-get purge openssh-client openssh-server` then installing them again after restarting my computer. Didn't work!
4. Changing the port from 22 to 2222 but then the connection timed out, I tried it using `ssh -p 2222` and with changing it from the config file. I also tried other ports, they timed out.
5. I checked `sudo ufw status` port 22 is allowed in anywhere.
6. Some people suggested that it might have to do with known_hosts, I have removed that but still the same problem.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated because this thing is driving me crazy.

Comment: make sure server is running on 0.0.0.0:22 and not 127.0.0.1:22.  check with `sudo netstat -anp | grep sshd`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just checked, it's on 0.0.0.0:22

Comment: What does `ssh -vv username@somehost` give you?

Comment: `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "somehost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to somehost [139.19.94.101] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 139.19.94.101 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host somehost port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: I took the liberty of `ssh`ing to contact.mpi-inf.mpg.de and got a connection rightaway. So it's a client issue, not a server issue.

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned it's the problem from my computer and not the server. I tried connecting from another device and it works just fine. But thanks :)